# How "access" a newly created div element in a script which ran before the element creation?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Suppose I have an html page

```
<html> 
    <body>
      <button onclick="add_product()">
        ADD 
     </button>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="static/script1.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="static/script2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

where `script1.js` is

```
function add_product(){
    const add_product_div = document.createElement("div");
    add_product_div.id = "add_product";
    add_product_div.className = "draggable_box";
    add_product_div.innerHTML="<h1> hey </h1> <p> whatevea </p> ";
    document.body.appendChild(add_product_div);
}
```

Now how can I access the newly created div `draggable_box` in `script2.js`

```
div = document.getElementsByClassName("draggable_box");
console.log(div)
```

`console.log(div)`
Gives a empty list as `script2.js` had already run before I added the element `draggable_box`.

I am new to web development! Essentially I want to use `script2.js` to make all the `div` I create draggable, I know how to do this when the script is run after the div is created. Please suggest the correct way to do this!

Comment: Without creating div, how would you be able to access that ? You can not do that

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to handle it in the button click that creates the element?

Comment: @ray I guess I thought it will be better to have separate scripts for different purposes. 
Like I said I am new to web dev, so I don't know what the conventions are.

Comment: @SrushtiShah, I want to access it after I create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this. Here are a few. The first would be most common and require the least effort. The other two would be somewhat unusual and I'm mostly including them to illustrate that there's more than one way to do this.

You could have your `add_product` function return the new div so the caller can do other stuff with it after it's created:

```js
function add_product(){
    const add_product_div = document.createElement("div");
    add_product_div.id = "add_product";
    add_product_div.className = "draggable_box";
    add_product_div.innerHTML="<h1> hey </h1> <p> whatevea </p> ";
    document.body.appendChild(add_product_div);
    return add_product_div; // return the new div
}

function onProductButtonClick () {
  const div = add_product(); // append a new div and get a reference to it
  console.log(div); // do other stuff with the new div
}

const button = document.getElementById('addProductButton');
button.addEventListener('click', onProductButtonClick)
```

```html
<button id="addProductButton">Add Product</button>
```

---

You could have `add_product` [emit an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) that other code can listen for:

```js
function add_product() {
  const add_product_div = document.createElement("div");
  add_product_div.id = "add_product";
  add_product_div.className = "draggable_box";
  add_product_div.innerHTML = "<h1> hey </h1> <p> whatevea </p> ";
  document.body.appendChild(add_product_div);

  // emit a 'productadded' event
  document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
    'productadded',
    {
      detail: {
        target: add_product_div
       }
     }
   ));
}

const button = document.getElementById('addProductButton');
button.addEventListener('click', add_product);

function onAdded(e) {
  console.log(e.detail.target);
}

// listen for 'productadded' events
document.body.addEventListener('productadded', onAdded);
```

```html
<button id="addProductButton">Add Product</button>
```

---

You could have a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) that alerts you when nodes get added to the DOM:

```js
function add_product() {
  const add_product_div = document.createElement("div");
  add_product_div.id = "add_product";
  add_product_div.className = "draggable_box";
  add_product_div.innerHTML = "<h1> hey </h1> <p> whatevea </p> ";
  document.body.appendChild(add_product_div);
}


function initObserver() {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
      console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', initObserver);

const button = document.getElementById('addProductButton');
button.addEventListener('click', add_product);
```

```html
<button id="addProductButton">Add Product</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort! Your answer is very educational for me and I will adopt one of the methods you have suggested.